firewalld blocking packet return using keepalived
I configured a keepalived to work as a loadbalancer. I am not using the configuration for Master/Standby server, it's a single server.
The problem is: if I don't have firewalld running everything works but with firewalld, the packet returning from the real server is blocked with STATE_INVALID_DROP.
The firewall has eth0 (external zone) and eth1 (nm-shared zone). eth0->eth1 is OK, the blcok is eth1->eth0.
Using only firewalld with route defined to reach the real server and removing keepalived it works as well. Only when they are together I have problem.
